# Cocos 2dx - CCDrawNode boundingbox.size always {0,0}

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am new to cocos 2dx.

How we find the bounding box of CCDrawNode? It always show "outside poly".

My code is:

```
  void HelloWorld :: drawAlpha(){  
     CCPoint points[25] = {ccp(435,190), ccp(360, 200), ccp(315, 135), ccp(289,100), ccp(206,100),ccp(160,150),ccp(145,215),ccp(155,290),ccp(168,340),ccp(225,370),ccp(285,370),ccp(320,340),ccp(350,260),ccp(445,280),ccp(420,390),ccp(340,470),ccp(219,470),ccp(120,450),ccp(40,334),ccp(30,200),ccp(65,90),ccp(150,5),ccp(202,5),ccp(346,5),ccp(430,90)};

       CCDrawNode* polygon = CCDrawNode :: create();
        polygon -> drawPolygon(points, 25, ccc4f(1,0,0,0.5), 6.0, ccc4f(0,0,1,1));
        polygon -> setPosition(ccp( 300, 300));
        CCLOG("Width : %f", polygon -> boundingBox().size.width);
        this -> addChild(polygon);
    }

void HelloWorld:: ccTouchesBegan(CCSet* pTouches, CCEvent* event){
    touchPosition = (CCTouch*) pTouches -> anyObject();
    touchLocation = touchPosition -> getLocation();


    if(polygon -> boundingBox().containsPoint(touchLocation)){
        CCLOG("inside poly");
    }
    else{
        CCLOG("outside poly");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you set it manually, it will always return empty size.

Since Node is a simple container it doesn't calculate bounding-box automatically. You have to find min x, min y, and max x and max y from point array, then you can calculate bounding rect easily.

Comment: ok..bounding box is in rectangle shape.. but i want user touches only inside polygon, I make a polygon using CCDrawNode, so what I have to do??

Comment: hey!!  i am explaining you the problem now i have…

i have a complex shape polygon and i  want to draw color only in that polygon but if i make bounding box it is in rectangle form, so user also draws outside it but i want user draws only inside that polygon means i want to use polygon as a boundary condition.. so what will i have to do now???